# How to prevent event of jPlayer

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I want to prevent some events of jPlayer. My business condition says that when user listen audio for 2 times then I have to stop playing audio, for this I am trying  `event.preventDefault()` but it's not working, code as below:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) { 
        if(cnt==2)
        {
        event.preventDefault();}
    });
```

But this code is not working, How can I prevent an event of `jPlayer`.

Comment: You can't, unless you edit the source code of the plugin.

Comment: @Spokey Ohh can you give me hint how to do it? and is it allowed?

Comment: If you want to stop people playing the video, why bother even having it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hey why downvote!! It was just an example. and what if I want to stop playing on an business condition. I want to stop playing audio when user listen it for two times.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it would be best to put details like that in the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I apologize, question updated.

Comment: You can't do it like this because the events are probably triggered internally (and preventDefault doesn't what what you think it does). You could for example trigger the stop event instead of preventDefault(). If you would create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or use the stack snippets you might get help faster since people will be able to directly work with the code, that doesn't mean that you don't have to try it yourself first.

Comment: @Spokey yes I tried but just in regular manner like Jquery. Thanks for your help. and everyone can't think in same manner. I tried I failed so I asked.

Comment: Where is `cnt` coming from in this context?

Comment: @TZHX I am incrementing on event `$.jPlayer.event.ended`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a dirty way by using the plugin events...

```
var cnt = 0;
$('#player').jPlayer({
   /* options here ... */
   play: function(){
      if (cnt == 2) $(this).jPlayer('stop');
   },
   ended: function(){
      cnt++;
   }
});
```

You can't prevent the play event but you can trigger the stop event to deny it. The audio will only play 2 times. Note that the cnt increases only when the audio/video reached the end and not if the video gets paused, or stopped. You might want to remove the pause or stop controls.